# python call async function from sync

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an asynchronous function that makes http requests and receives json:

```
async def query_async(name):

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://example.com/' + name) as resp:
            response = await resp.json()
            return response
```

I want to call this function in synchronous code, like this:

```
def prepare_result():
    name = 'some_url'
    response = asyncio.run(query_async(name))
    ...
```

Questions:

- will I have a win if the synchronous function has the ability to be called simultaneously via the web?
- am I calling the async function correctly from synchronous code?

Comment: Can you clarify your first question: what do you mean by synchronous function having "the ability to be called simultaneously via the web"? Your "async" code doesn't appear to use any benefits of asyncio because you only call one coroutine at the same time.

Comment: @user4815162342 I mean a synchronous function will be in a web-app and will be called simultaneously through gunicorn, for example

Comment: Then what do you mean by "have a win"? It should work, yes, but I don't think it will be any faster than if you used `requests` or similar. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @user4815162342 ok, such situation, I call an asynchronous function, it makes a request and until the response arrives, it will take 5 seconds, before the end of these 5 seconds, I call the asynchronous function again.
If this were a synchronous function, I would have to wait for a response (i.e. those 5 seconds). And in the case of async?  is there any benefit  in such an implementation?

Comment: `asyncio.run()` is synchronous, not async, so at the point of its invocation you lose the benefits of async.